# Alternative choices beside Silverlight AspDotNetMembershipProvider

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-membership

i'm doing with silverlight 4 for consultation booking system. what i wondering is, in my application required multiple kind of user register and login. admin having different format of admin ID, lecturer having different format of lecturer ID. i'm trying to implement with silverlight for role and authentication merchant. i think might because of silverlight membership can be done easily with asp.netmembershipprover, i could not find any resource to edit the default form for it or custom made the membership merchant for my application. may i know is there any article or resource you know on how to implement this, or any idea you can suggest to me ?? Thank you

Resources i found:
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-(silverlight-quickstart) 
i thinking of using the isolated storage to store the user logged in boolean but sound like not so secure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942451(v=vs.91).aspx
the resources mention of using the default asp.net membership but no comment on how to edit the default set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) to manage general user information such as username, password, security question, login etc. Then you create additional table to store your own information, of course you need to create Page to manage these data by yourself.

```
Table: aspnet_users
       UserId
       UserName
       ...

Table: YourCustomData
       UserId
       AdminId
       AdminText
       ...
```

Comment: because i need to having lecturer login, student login and admin login seperately >.< if i want to custom made form authentication such as what we does usually in asp.net mvc with authentication ticket... is that possible with silverlight ??

Comment: Yes, `Membership` has separate authentication and role mechanism. User and password of all user store in one table and it has separate table name aspnet_UsersInRoles to store which user has which role.

Comment: because i seriously never touch that, may i get some link of tutorial from you.. please

Comment: This is good start point: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/05/03/accessing-the-asp-net-authentication-profile-and-role-service-in-silverlight.aspx